# Ошибка → Добавление записи в MySQL через html-форму

Tags: php, html, html5

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь выучить язык PHP. Затормозил на добавлении записи в MySQL через html-форму.
Html форма:

```html
<?php
include_once "header.php"?>
<?php
include_once "menu.php"?>
<?php include_once "leftblock.php"?>


<div class="content"
<form aсtion="/connect.php" method="post">
    <label>Логин: </label>
    <input type="text" name="Pоle1" placeholder="Логин"><br>
    <label>Пароль:</label>
    <input type="password" name="Pоle2" placeholder="Пароль"><br>
    <label>Повторите пароль:</label>
    <input type="password" name="Pоle3" placeholder="Повторите пароль"><br>
    <label>Введите телефон:</label>
    <input type="tel" name="Pole4" placeholder=введите ваш телефон>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Регистрация">

</form>



</div>
<?php include_once "footer.php"?>
```

php форма:

```html
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "host1435288";
$password = "225a32a8";
$db = "host1435288_wwwnvr";
$connect = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die ('error');
$select_db = mysql_select_db($db) or die ('error');?>

<?php
$i=$_POST['Pоle1'];
$f=$_POST['Pоle2'];
$n=$_POST['Pоle3'];
$o=$_POST['Pоle4'];
$link = mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","") or die ("Невозможно подключение к MySQL");
mysql_select_db("dog") or die ("Невозможно открыть таблицу с данными");

$query =  ("INSERT INTO prepod (Pole1,Pole2,Pole3,Pole2) VALUES ('".$i."', '".$f."', '".$n."', '".$o."')");
mysql_query ( $query );
if ($query == 'true')
  echo "Добавлено в базу данных.";

mysql_close ($link);

?>
```

mySql:

[image: MySql]

Не могу понять в чём ошибка.

Comment: Первым делом выкини на помойку учебник, в котором ты это все вычитал, и найди что-нибудь поновее

Comment: Да, согласен с комментарием @Ипатьев То, что вы сейчас пытаетесь изучить давным давно устарело. Лучше вовремя прекратить.

Comment: Может быть у человека учебная задача сделать что-то с помощью `mysql_*`. Для общих целей изучения принципов в т.ч. вэб программирования не важна конечная технология, PDO там будет или что-то другое. лучше на вопрос

Comment: по сабжу, выполнение запроса через `mysql_query` требует двух парметров. первый - строка запроса, второй - подключение. Так что код должен быть `$result = mysql_query($query, $link)`. После чего у вас в `$result` будет `true/false` в зависимости от выполнения. сравнивать `$query`  со _строкой_ `"true"` вообще бессмысленно, ибо в `$query` у вас текст запроса, а строка `"true"` вообще не при делах. Так что `if($result){ ... }`

Comment: @teran я всегда предполагал что у здешних обитателей с логикой нелады, но чтобы настолько...

Comment: @teran Второй параметр не обязателен. Если используется одно подключение, использование ссылки на подключение не нужно. Функции давно устарели, а вы все еще не знаете как их использовать.

Comment: @Ипатьев в чем претензия то у вас? Я вроде не говорю, что использование `mysql_*` это хорошо, и вроде не против перехода на `PDO` и т.п. В школах начинают изучать с бэйсика, а в универе часто паскаль. Для академических целей не важно, на сколько устаревшая или нет технология. Разобравшись с такой задачей и примером он должен ясно понимать, что такие технологии использовались 10 лет назад, и а сам код занимает хорошее среднее место из рада _говнокода_. Так что может хамить не будете и сформулируете нормальным языком?

Comment: @teran `mysql_query ( $query ) or die(mysql_error());` - вот, что вы должны были рекомендовать. А в итоге пишете бесполезный текст.

Comment: @ilyaplot простите мое невежество :) я 10 лет не пользовал эти функции. Более того я вообще никогда не писал кода, используя их без оберток, кроме как на учебе. В те далекие времена PEAR::DB был куда удобнее. А писать `or die(..)` я в целом не могу поощрять, ибо не вижу смысла выводить всем подряд сообщения о ошибках, а в случае ошибки выполнения зачастую требуется какая-то логика дальнейших действий, а не тупо умереть. Как по мне как-то убого видеть белую страницу на сайте с надписью sql connection failed или с выводом тела косячного sql запроса

Comment: а данные доходят? я тут в `action` заметил русскую букву `с`

Comment: @EvilGatsby, напишите в вопросе, в чём именно заключается ошибка.